# Linux assembly woes

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Is there really no way to print an ascii string in assembly to standard output without using up all four general purpose registers?

Comment: Intel or AT&T syntax aside (it makes no difference), Tom is asking if you are talking about Intel x86 assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, it takes three registers for the parameters plus one for the system call number...

But, x86 has `pusha` and `popa`, which will push and pop all the registers in one instruction.

```
$ cat hwa.S
write = 0x04
exit  = 0xfc
.text
_start:
        pusha
        movl    $1, %ebx
        lea     str, %ecx
        movl    $len, %edx
        movl    $write, %eax
        int     $0x80
        popa
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
        movl    $exit, %eax
        int     $0x80
.data
str:    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
len = . -str
.globl  _start
$ as -o hwa.o hwa.S
$ ld hwa.o
$ ./a.out
Hello, world!
```

Comment: What? That takes ten clock cycles for the pusha and popa. The eight independent pushes and pops take one each. If you're going to get down and dirty with assembly, you've got to keep the faith and run at max speed :-)

Comment: In any case, you could just create your own system call that used eax for the code and ebx for the address of a null-terminated string. Voila (although you'll need to convince Linus et al to get it into the mainstream kernel) - let me know how that goes :-)

Comment: Heh, si, but 10 cycles@3 GHz, I'll wait :-)

Comment: where do you get your clock measurements?

Answer (score 1):

Well..  If you linked against libc you can call `puts`, then you'd have some callee-save registers...  :-)

But yeah.  The syscall interface is pass-by-register.  Sorry.

Don't be so shocked.  It'd be the same way if you were doing a function call on some calling conventions.  For many platforms that's pretty standard.  (Including all amd64 compilers I know of...)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that takes the needed arguments from the stack.